# flutter is not updating android licenses

Tags: android, flutter

when I run flutter doctor I get the following response.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1 at /home/farhan/src/flutter
    • Framework revision c382b8e990 (8 months ago), 2019-08-18 15:22:36 -0400
    • Engine revision 5540684152
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/farhan/src/sdk-tools-linux-4333796
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/farhan/src/sdk-tools-linux-4333796
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/farhan/src/sdk-tools-linux-4333796
    • Java binary at: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04-b08)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 7.0 (API 24) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

so I ran flutter doctor --android-licenses. After accepting the licenses this is the response I get back

```
Accept? (y/N): y
All SDK package licenses accepted
```

tried flutter doctor --android-licenses again and got the same response back

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1 at /home/farhan/src/flutter
    • Framework revision c382b8e990 (8 months ago), 2019-08-18 15:22:36 -0400
    • Engine revision 5540684152
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/farhan/src/sdk-tools-linux-4333796
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/farhan/src/sdk-tools-linux-4333796
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/farhan/src/sdk-tools-linux-4333796
    • Java binary at: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04-b08)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 7.0 (API 24) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: I recommend you to install android studio. Then Tools > SDK Manager > Android SDK > SDK Platforms and install Platform android-28

Answer (score 0):

oaky install Android Studio then Then Tools > SDK Manager > Android SDK > SDK Platforms and install Platform android-28

if issue solved then good or else 
do this
After doing that open your code editor's terminal and type in flutter doctor --android-license then, keep on accepting the license by pressing 'y'.